# Regarding the approach of a recursive to iterative past year paper question

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

How would you convert this recursive function into iterative?

```
int sum(int n) {
if (n < 1) return 1;
return sum(n - 1) * (n - 1) + n;
```

Can I do it like this? (Refer below)

```
int sum(int n){
    if(n<1) return 1;

    while(n >= 1){
        sum = sum(n-1) * (n-1) + n;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is still in a recursive form.

Observe that you have a base case, i.e. where n = 0. This is the initial value of your sum. You can then iterate over n, for each iteration applying the formula given for the sum. The iterative case, then, looks like this:

```
int sum_iterative (int n) {
    int sum = 1; //n = 0
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = sum * (i-1) + i; //sum(n-1) * (n-1) + n
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why is sum initialised to 1 instead of 0?

Comment: This is equivalent to the recursive base case; `if (n < 1) return 1;`